# How to manage multiple calls to Membership.GetUser() efficiently

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership

I have multiple calls to Membership.GetUser() and can't seem to find anything built in to cope with this (without hitting the database multiple times).

I first looked into static variables before realising this was not suitable. I know I can use sessions but I would need to hash/encrypt the userID to make it safe, which is fine but I didn't want to do this without checking if there was a built in way to do this within the .net membership provider

Is there a built in way of remembering a value like the UserID and safely storing that for the current user?

Comment: If you throw it into the session, why would you need to encrypt the user id?

Comment: Couldn't someone spoof the value? Is all session data stored on the server side with a reference on the client?

Comment: @Andi the session object only lives on the server. The only thing sent to the client is a session id.

Comment: I missunderstood that, thought it could be cookie based (had this idea from my old PHP coding days) Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: Are you trying to prevent multiple calls during a single request or during the whole session?

Comment: During a single request, although session would be ok.

Comment: If you decide to use sessions keep in mind that if you have a server farm you need to keep the session in a centralized repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Membership.GetUser() is an indirect call to the class MembershipProvider's method:

```
public abstract MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline);
```

So, you can write a class that derives from the MembershipProvider you're using (for example SqlMembershipProvider or ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, or a custom one) and override this method using some clever cache mechanism.

Then you will need to change the web.config to declare this new MembershipProvider class:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="MyProvider" type="...MyProvider" ... />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using the [Singleton-per-Request pattern](http://dotnetslackers.com/community/blogs/simoneb/archive/2006/08/21/The-ASP.NET-Singleton_2D00_per_2D00_Request-pattern.aspx) which uses the [HttpContext.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx) property.

```
public class UserPerRequest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the result of Membership.GetUser(), but will cache the results within the
    /// current request so it's only called once per request.
    /// </summary>
    public static MembershipUser Current
    {
        get
        {
            const string key = "UserPerRequest";

            if (HttpContext.Current.Items[key] == null)
                HttpContext.Current.Items[key] = Membership.GetUser();

            return (MembershipUser)HttpContext.Current.Items[key];
        }
    }
}
```

So everywhere you'd call `Membership.GetUser()` just call `UserPerRequest.Current` instead.  The only time you'll still get multiple calls to the database during a request is if `Membership.GetUser()` returns null.

Comment: I think the code in the article is slightly more efficient because it doesn't have to lookup the newly added item in collection, but I thought my version was a little easier to read for SO.

Comment: Any comments on this approach?